# Back to top button not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm trying to create a simple back to to button with jQuery which works well in Chrome but it doesn't work in Firefox and IE. Actually the JSFiddle below doesn't work even in Chrome.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hb3qf/)

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div>
   <span>My long text here.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="back-to-top" onclick="backToTop()"></div>
</body>
```

javaScript:

```
function backToTop () {
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 700);
}
```

And I'm using the latest jQuery library.

Comment: JSFiddle doesn't work because it doesn't like inline javascript, you should get into the habbit of not using it because it is nasty. You should register events like: `$(".back-to-top").click(backToTop);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change it to

```
function backToTop () {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 700);
}
```

IE and firefox attaches the scrollbar to the `html` element, while chrome uses `body`

The reason your fiddle doesn't work is because you're using the "onload" handler, which wraps the javascript in a function, so your function is out of scope.

Here's a working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hb3qf/1/)